# How to delete lots of nodes

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I want to delete all nodes of a given type and their relations. In total there are 1.4 million nodes of this type.

Using `MATCH (n:Type) DETACH DELETE n` Neo4j hangs itself up after a few minutes and has to be restarted.

Is there a better way to delete a large number of nodes? Can I delete them in chunks somehow (LIMIT is not supported with DELETE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Match (n:Type) with n
Match (n)-[r]-()
Delete n, r
```

If you want to delete them in chunks the query would look like

```
Match (n:Type) with n limit 1000
Match (n)-[r]-()
Delete n, r
```

Comment: The first query still crashed neo4j. The second query with a limit of 500000 did the job fairly quick.